# nvim insert mode breaks keyboard layout on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, vim

When I enter Insert mode in nvim 0.4.3, other keyboard layouts are not available, but the icon at the top right is changing.

I'm using GNOME as DE.

[Here's my .vimrc](https://gist.github.com/Legomegger/279de66fec46072ca77931fcbe34737b)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution: the problem was with *rlue/vim-barbaric* nvim plugin, seems like it's conflicting with something; I just turned it off and everything is now working perfectly!